# simple mysql search engine

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a open source script. (https://github.com/keverw/Random-Quotes)

```
SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE text LIKE '%$searchTermbox%' AND OR author LIKE '%$searchTermbox%' LIMIT 15
```

I'm trying to make a simple search engine where it searches both text and author and also won't have duplicates. Any ideas? So if i type in "Kevin" it would show both authors with that name and Quotes mentioning them.

So AND OR because somethings they both will mention it or they both won't.... Any ideas how to write something very simple like this? I'm very basic at MySQL.

`id | text | time | author | approved` is the Structure. Also approved needs to = 1

Comment: Could you show your table structures?

Comment: @Sergey I knew iw as forgetting something... Thanks! Added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `AND`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM quotes 
WHERE text LIKE '%$searchTermbox%' 
    OR author LIKE '%$searchTermbox%' 
LIMIT 15
```

This will select all quotes where either text or author or both contain `$searchTermbox`.

This is because when using `OR`, the `AND` case is covered as well. By default, `a OR b` means `a, b or both`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that using `LIKE '%...'` is generally inefficient since it requires every record in the table be individually scanned, and cannot take advantage of indexes.  Generally, the more efficient method for this type of problem is to use a full text index, which MySQL supports (see, e.g., http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

This approach requires first creating the full-text index (a one-time operation), and then using a specialized syntax to query the data (in place of the `LIKE` operator).

To create the full text index (assuming quotes is a MyISAM table), you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE quotes ADD FULLTEXT (author, text);
```

Then the equivalent query expression can be written as:

```
SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE MATCH (author, text) AGAINST ('$searchTermbox')
  AND APPROVED=1
  LIMIT 15;
```

This should provide the same results as the earlier query, but may be significantly faster, particularly if the database is large.